# Website security testing shows possible XSS vulnerabilities even with no script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, security

I'm trying to secure my web app against XSS vulnerabilities as much as possible, but before I figure out how to use Microsoft's AntiXSS library to encode all input/output, I decided to experiment with something first.

What I did was get rid of all the methods in my Web Service class. So it now looks like this:

```
namespace ProjectName.Web.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AJAXService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,
    // uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AJAXService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Why would the scan still show AJAXService as being vulnerable to XSS? Is there a property or attribute that needs to be set, or some default method that is hidden? I'm using ASMX because it's purely for AJAX and it's what I'm used to.

(The tool I used for scanning is Acunetix)

Comment: Encoding all input / output will not defend against all attacks.  You should only encode when concatenating into a string, and you must always use the correct escape mechanism.

Comment: the javascript on a site has little or nothing to do with XSS issues, which is a server-based problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but is `ValidateRequest` set to false in the page directive? Maybe it's not related to the web service itself, but rather a security feature (or lack thereof) on the page that is consuming it?

Comment: I just checked, and ValidateRequest is set to true (it's not declared and the default is true)

Comment: Could you update your post to include the output details of how it is vulnerable?